# How do I add support/resistance levels in freqtrade?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, cryptocurrency

I would like to add support/resistance levels to my freqtrade strategy. I followed this [tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/detection-of-price-support-and-resistance-levels-in-python-baedc44c34c9) and plotted out support/resistance levels using matplotlib. I would like to do something similar on freqtrade. I used the [technical.pivots_points](https://github.com/freqtrade/technical/blob/master/technical/pivots_points.py) library in hopes of doing this but it did not work. Is there a way to do this?

The purple line is the resistance when using thechnical.pivots_points:
[image]

What I would like it to look like:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
from freqtrade.strategy.interface import IStrategy
from pandas import DataFrame
import talib.abstract as ta

class SupportResistanceStrategy(IStrategy):
    # ... (other strategy parameters and methods)

    plot_config = {
        'main_plot': {
            'support': {
                'color': 'green',
                'style': '-',
            },
            'resistance': {
                'color': 'red',
                'style': '-',
            },
        },
    }

    def populate_indicators(self, dataframe: DataFrame, metadata: dict) -> DataFrame:
        # ... (other indicator calculations)

        # Identify support and resistance levels
        dataframe['support'] = ta.SMA(dataframe['close'], timeperiod=50)
        dataframe['resistance'] = ta.SMA(dataframe['close'], timeperiod=200)

        return dataframe
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).